# Is the following set is connected ?6

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the following set is connected ?
[image]

MY attempt :  since the map  is continious , so f^-1 (f-inverse) is open and dense, but main point is that f^-1(R-0) is open that is 0 is removed from the R.
So the set K is not connceted and not path connected.

Is my answer is correct or not,,as i don't know the proper proof .
PLiz help me and tell me the solution..

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

If both $ f, g \in K $, it's very easy to check that $ u f + (1-u) g \in K $ for every $ u \in \mathbb R $, so the map $ [0, 1] \to K $ defined by $ u \to u f + (1-u) g $ gives a path between $ f $ and $ g $. (Continuity follows trivially since $ f, g $ are bounded.) Hence, $ K $ is path connected, and is therefore connected.

Comment: im not getting if we take  f(x) = x,,,i mean it is not bounded ,,and for connected  here f(x)  is not  zero,,,,that  Q.  how can u claim that its is path connected?

Comment: To the proposer: "It is not bounded."  What is IT? .......And what does it matter whether f(x) is 0?